# hibernate FullTextEntityManager query with ORM id subquery failing to fire

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I have a fulltext query which under advice from a previous question I have filtered with an Id query.  For some reason the query fails to fire (I'm sure it fired before but...)  Can anyone see why ?

```
    Class<?> entityClass = entityType.getJavaType();

    List<String> fields = buildFields(entityType.getProperties());

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(getEntityManager());

    SearchFactory searchFactory = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory();
    QueryContextBuilder queryContextBuilder = searchFactory.buildQueryBuilder();
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = queryContextBuilder.forEntity(entityClass).get();

    CriteriaBuilder idBuilder = m_storage.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery idQuery = idBuilder.createQuery(entityClass);

    Root from = idQuery.from(entityClass);        
    idQuery.select(from.get("OID"));

    Subquery<Long> subquery = idQuery.subquery(Long.class);
    Root dateSQ = subquery.from(entityClass);

    subquery.select(idBuilder.max(dateSQ.get("modDateTime")));
    subquery.groupBy(dateSQ.get("surname"));



idQuery.where(idBuilder.in(from.get("modDateTime")).value(subquery));
    TypedQuery typedQuery = m_storage.createQuery(idQuery);
    List<Long> ids = typedQuery.getResultList();

    BooleanJunction<?> idJunction = queryBuilder.bool();
    for (Long id : ids) {
           idJunction.must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("recId").matching(id).createQuery());
    }

    SearchOption searchOption = uriInfo.getSearchOption();

    Query query = queryBuilder.bool()
                .must(processSearchExpression(searchOption.getSearchExpression(), queryBuilder,
            fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]))).filteredBy(idJunction.createQuery())
             .createQuery();

    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, entityClass);

    return fullTextQuery;

//fullTextQuery fails to run
```

If I remove the filter and so

```
query = queryBuilder.bool()
                .must(processSearchExpression(searchOption.getSearchExpression(), queryBuilder,
            fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()])))
             .createQuery();
```

The query runs but obviously doesn't filter by ids.  There are ids in the filter.  When I set a showSQL to true I see a query if I don't have the filter but I don't get a query displayed when I have the filter (but no error is thrown)

I can't seem to find any problem ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the query doesn't fire":

1. If you called `typedQuery.getResultList();`, a query was definitely executed.
2. The Hibernate Search query doesn't use SQL, so "setting a showSQL to true" will not help. You need to use a different option to [trace Hibernate Search queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#query-logging).

Anyway, I assume your problem is rather that the query does not return any hit? That's a problem with the way you wrote your query. You wrote this:

```java
    BooleanJunction<?> idJunction = queryBuilder.bool();
    for (Long id : ids) {
           idJunction.must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("recId").matching(id).createQuery());
    }
```

... which means "the field 'recId' must have every single one of these id values".

Instead of "must", you should use "should":

```java
    BooleanJunction<?> idJunction = queryBuilder.bool();
    for (Long id : ids) {
           idJunction.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("recId").matching(id).createQuery());
    }
```

... which means "the field 'recId' must have at least one of these id values".

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit under the cosh at the minute but I'll check the documentation you sent.  I have 2 versions running though and I'm sure the other version (without the ID junction) was spitting out some SQL debug.  Anyway thanks for the explanation I misunderstood should and thought it might be fuzzy (how that would work on a boolean I'm not sure ;-) )